# Reek SublimeLinter Setup Issues

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter, reek

I've been trying to get the Reek Linter plugin working with Sublime Text 3 on my OSX machine and I'm having no luck.

The plugin is called `SublimeLinter-contrib-reek`. I've followed the instructions on the package [homepage](https://github.com/codequest-eu/SublimeLinter-contrib-reek) and it's still not working.

When I enable debug mode I get this error in the console:

```
SublimeLinter: ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1' 
SublimeLinter: reek version query: /Users/David/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby -S reek -v 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: no reek version could be extracted from:
/Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem reek (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
  from /Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
  from /Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/reek:23:in `<main>'

SublimeLinter:           using cmd: ['/Users/David/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby', '-S', 'reek', '-v'], env: {'USER': 'David', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/4h/2z9m8s3d2pngdjxdvynfb90m0000gn/T/', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LC_CTYPE': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'HOME': '/Users/David', 'XML_CATALOG_FILES': ' file:///etc/xml/catalog file:///etc/xml/catalog.xml', 'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/David/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/David/Documents/Development/tools/infer-osx-v0.1.0/infer/infer/bin:/usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-1.7.5.0//bin:/Users/David/.rvm/bin', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5GF3JtTX5B/Listeners', 'LOGNAME': 'David', 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf8', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': 'com.sublimetext.3.1880', 'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4bQlKdCF7j/Render', 'DISPLAY': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HsWI5bJQqo/org.macosforge.xquartz:0', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0x0:0xF'} 
environment variables loaded using: /bin/bash -l
```

Any assistance would be most grateful.

Comment: is `reek` in `/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1`? you need to use bundle/gem or something to install reek into that rvm

Comment: Yes.
```$ which reek``` yeilds ```/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/reek```